# Dummy app dependencies

Tags: ember-cli

I'd like the dummy app to have some dependencies that are not shared for the addon itself,
Is it possible at all?

For now, I do some workarounds in index.js such:

```
var isDummy = app.project.pkg.name === 'ember-idx-forms'

if (isDummy) {
  app.import('...');
}
```

Is there a better approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The addon contains it's own `Brocfile.js` that is used for exactly this. Simply import whatever you want in there. It is not used in the consuming applications.

[See here for docs on this](http://www.ember-cli.com/#addon-brocfile)

Answer (score 1):

Should be added to Broccoli.js as stated in ember-cli docs:

> The addon’s Brocfile.js is only used to configure the dummy application found in tests/dummy/. It is never referenced by applications which include the addon.

Answer (score 0):

For that you use the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` sections in your package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "some-package": "v1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "some-test-package": "v1"
  }
}
```

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: This is not enough, because if you have an import statement for an un-existing dependency broccoli will fail.

Comment: Of course you have to specify the environment in Broccoli too. `app.import` accepts a hash with includes for development and testing.

Comment: This is still not sufficient, because if you have devDependency X for the dummy (which runs in dev mode), the import statement will run when user starts its app (as the env is dev mode too).